# Cell communication

Tags: cell-biology

In some organism we observe that different individual cells organize and form structures. How are these individual cells attaining the information for the grouping? How does these cells communicate?

Comment: Welchome to Stack exchange! While this question may seem basic / simple, it is actually a super broad question: Cell communication & organisation encompasses large parts of [developmental biology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developmental_biology) and [cell signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_signaling) - both of which are very large & active fields of research. You can check the [Tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) center, which may help you to narrow your question down to a point where we can reasonably answer it.